# What Folder should I import into android studio so I can open an existing project?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-studio-import

I am trying to import a Gradle project into Android Studio, I tried and it stucked to Building Gradle project, what folder directory should I import
Attached the directory of the project and the directory of a sample in it.

It is stuck at this in the Welcome page of Android Studio
[image: Stuck at this]

[image: Master Folder]
[image: CpcPcscSample Folder]

Answer (score 1):

To open an exixting android project

In android studio goto file -> new -> import project

and then select your existing android project and it will opened without any problem

Comment: You have src folder, gradle,  etc... all in one folder and import it

Comment: For example you have project name called My Application and select it to import

Comment: I see the problem now, I was doing this but it asks me to overwrite the existing project so I refuse and rename it, if I overwrite the project will open correctly .

Comment: Yes it will open correctly with the same name else if you want rename it

Answer (score 1):

New - open - select build.gradle file. (Note: In src also you have build.gradle file, don't select this one.You have to select outer most build.gradle file).